# How to edit files in target folder compiled by Maven

Tags: java, database, maven, database-schema

Currently I have to use a new and not well-documented corporate libraries, including a Maven plugin to generate Liquibase scripts in target folder from xml file. It generates changelog and changesets for creating database schemas automatically.

I want to add some Liquibase changesets to persist initial data into database. Unfortunately this plugin doesn't have a goal for it. And I can't edit changelog and include there my new changeset manually, because it is in target folder and will be recompiled by Maven.

Any ideas? Is there a Maven plugin to edit automatically generated changelog in target folder?

I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Simple answer is unfortunately: No. If the plugin does not what you it should change the plugin... to do what is needed...

Comment: I don't have access to the source code of this plugin or even a team, who developed it

Comment: That's bad... but I don't any solution for it... just contact the team...if that's necessary for your work...it should be fixed...not by "hacky" solutions...

Comment: You write "_generate [...] from xml file_". Can't you add according configuration in this XML that's added to changelog/changeset then? If that's not possible I can think of [Maven Resource Filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) (which is in fact _string interpolation_).

Comment: You can create a thin maven plugin to run your library. I've written several. It's pretty easy to write a Mojo that accepts parameters from the pom.xml or from the command line.